# I need a way to order objects

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I need a data structure, similar to an object, but in my case, I need the keys to be objects by themselves:

```
tree = { { "a": 1, "t": "text }: 42 }
tree[ { 'b': true, 'c': 15 } ] = 'hello'
```

I could easily simulate this, if I where able to give two keys/object a [strikt weak order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering). But apparently `{ "a": 1 } < { "a": 2 }` doesn't yield anything useful. Even if I extract the key value pairs, and sort them by keys, I would have to find a way to compare the values within the key objects.

I could stringify the keys to a json string, but I'm not sure, if there is a guaranty, that when I do this, that the result will always be the same and this solution looks a little bit ugly to me.

Any ideas, tips or pointers on how to achieve such a data structure (easy, performant and elegant if possible)?

Edit: I need this for a publish / subscribe library. Nodes to be subscribed are named by an object. For the client side library, I have to do some book keeping to have the state of the subscription.

As an example, how could I sort this array:

```
[ { a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { a: true, b: false, c: "hello" }, { d:'yes' } ]
```

Comment: JavaScript has arrays and objects, that's it for data structures. Can you post a real example of why you need this? You should be able to represent your structure in JS somehow, with valid syntax.

Comment: @elclanrs Yes, but how would you give two objects an order?

Comment: You'd use a collection (an array of objects) if that's what you mean.

Comment: @elclanrs Yes, that would be possible, but for a linear search, I would have to compare the objects for equality, for a binary search, I need a strict weak order. That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: If you provide a real (simplified) example of what you want to do maybe someone can help. In what language would you design this structure?

Comment: I understand correctly, you want to order a bunch of objects by some (or many) of their properties?

Comment: @elclanrs I'm going to implement this in cofeescript. But a solution in javascript would be welcome too.

Comment: Yes, I want to give a list of objects a defined order.

Comment: Do you really need to be able to order arbitrary objects or just hash them to strings so that you can use them as Object keys?

Comment: I need to be able to store some data under some key and to retrieve that data, using an equal key. I basically see two possibilities, using a sorted list (using some order) or using a hash map (using a hash and a equality comparison). I think the first is easier to implement (as a simply sorted Array for example).

Answer (score 2):

> But apparently { "a": 1 } < { "a": 2 } doesn't yield anything useful. Even if I extract the key value pairs, and sort them by keys, I would have to find a way to compare the values within the key objects.

You can't compare objects, but you can write a function to check one object's value against another:

```
var arr = [
  { "a": 1 },
  { "a": 2 }
];

function test(obj1, obj2){
  return obj1.a < obj2.a;
}

console.log(test(arr[0], arr[1])); // true
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WznU6/3/)

Is that what you're looking for?

In addition, here's a method to sort an array of objects by key:

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.a < b.a)
    return -1;
  if (a.a > b.a)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

arr.sort(compare);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WznU6/9/)

Comment: As the objects act as keys and that keys, are provided by the users application, I don't know in advance, what keys the keys have, nor is it likely, that the keys will have all the same keys. I will add an example. Thanks a lot!